# Proof that the language $a^nb^ma^nb^m$ is not context free using the pumping lemma.

Tags: context-free-grammar, pumping-lemma

I need a proof that the language L = {$a^nb^ma^nb^m,\:n,m\geq0$} is context free using the pumping lemma. My problem is that I can actually show the conditions of the lemma hold for this language and thus it wouldn't help in disproving the context freeness of this language. In order to do that, I can take $s=uvxyz$ to be $u=a^nb^{m-1}$, $v=b$, $x=a^n$, $y=b$, and $z=b^{m-1}$ and let the constant $p$ (or $m$ in some references) be $p=n+2$; then no matter how I pump $v$ and $y$ up or down, still the number of $b$s would be the same on both sides and with the same order and the resulting string would still be in L. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You don't get to pick your own $p$. $p$ is fixed for a CFG $L$ - it cannot be a variable (can't depend on $n$)

Comment: @Kaind I'm not choosing $p$. I'm holding a constraint on it to show that such $p$ indeed always exists. Obviously $n$ is a variable and $p$ can't be chosen a fixed constant depending on $n$!

Comment: p is constant for all words in that language. You can't have $p = 4$ for $a^4b^4a^4b^4$ and $p = 3$ for   $a^3b^3a^3b^3$ for the same language.

Comment: @Kaind Oh I see your point. I was more concerned with the question than the nuisances of the lemma at the time of writing it. Let's just say that $s$ is sufficiently large. I apologize for my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $L$ is a CFL with pumping length $p \geq 1$.

Then consider the string $s = a^pb^pa^pb^p$. Clearly $|s| \geq p$. Let $s'$ be the pumped string. For $s' \in L$, either $v = x = b \lor v = x = a$ where $v$ and $x$ are taken from different occurrences of $b$ and $a$ respectively. But in this case $|vwx| \geq p+2$. **Qed**.

Comment: Okay, you're showing one instance of division to substrings that wouldn't work, but you must show that no division to substrings that satisfies the lemma constraints is possible. How can you show that the one I have provided is wrong?

Comment: @FriendlyFella Apologies, I was using Ogden's lemma in my earlier answer instead of pumping lemma. I've edited it to use Pumping lemma. (Although do check Ogden's lemma - it makes the job much easier)

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand how $v = x = b \lor v = x = a$. If we had taken $v=y=b$ in $s$ and pumped it $i$ times, they would be $v=y=b^i$ in $s'$ and $x$ would remain $a^n$ since we're not touching it. I believe you're working it from the other direction and producing $s$ substrings from $s'$, but I don't see how you're doing it.

Comment: @FriendlyFella I take $s = uvwxy$ instead of $uvxyz$. Do you see it now?

Comment: Not really, since they might as well be substrings like $b^i$.

Comment: Ok, answer this: Given that $s = a^pb^pa^pb^p$, what are the ways to pump s, so that each pumped string is still in $L$? I'm saying there are two, when ..<fill in here> ? And my argument says, that for either of the 2 pumpings, there is no valid subdivision of $s$ into $uvwxy$.

Comment: I get it now! THANKS! I figure out that I need a better reference to study since it's not paying enough attention to $P$!

Answer (score 0):

If $L$ is a CFL, there is a constant $N$ so that all strings in $L$ longer than $N$ can be divided as $u v w x y$, with $\lvert v w x \rvert \le N$ and $v x \ne \varepsilon$ so that for all $k\ge0$ it is $u v^k w x^k y \in L$.
You want to contradict this.
Assume $L$ is a CFL, let $N$ be the lemma's constant for $L$. Pick some "easy" string in $L$,  say $a^N b^N a^N b^N$. Any division you may pick won't work with e.g. $k = 0$ (the parts pumped don't reach far enough to balance the pieces). Contradiction, $L$ isn't a CFL.

Comment: Here you're showing that $a^Nb^Na^Nb^N$ isn't a CFL which is pretty straight-forward, but it is a special case of this problem where $n=m=N$. If you pump $a^Nb^Na^Nb^N$ by the substrings I have provided you would still get $a^Nb^ma^Nb^m$ which still belongs to $L$.